# How to add session to PHP Login

Tags: php, mysql, session

This is the code I have included the sessions on and it's not working. I'm not sure what I have done wrong. Have I included the sessions in the wrong place on my login page? I am new to PHP so any help would be great. I have included my Login.php and my HomePage.php that I want to be protected.

Login.php

```php
<?php
// Always start this first
session_start();


$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//connect to server and database 

$conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "horses");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo "Success: a propper connection was made! <br>";
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($conn);
// Query the users table if there is matching rows equal to the $username
$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query ($conn, $myQuery);

$exists = $result->num_rows; //checks if username exists 

$table_users = "";
$table_password= "";

if ($exists > 0) 
{ //if there is no returning rows or no existing username 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    { //DISPLAY ALL ROWS FROM QUERY 
        // THE FIRST USERNAME ROW IS PASSED ONTO THE $TABLE_USERS, AND SO ON UNTILL THE QUERY IS FINISHED
        $table_users = $row ['username'];
        // the first password row is PAassed on to the $table_users and so on until the query is finished 
        $table_password = $row['password'];
        $table_role = $row['RoleID'];
    }//while
    // check if there are any mactching fields 
    if ($username == $table_users && ($password == $table_password)) 
    { 
        if ($table_role == 1)
            header ("location: CHomePage.php"); // takes the user to the Customer Homepage 
        else if ($table_role == 2) 
            header ("location: HomePage.php"); // takes the user to the Staff Homeage
    }//if
    else 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Username or Password!');</script>"; //Prompts the user 
        echo "<script>window.location.assign('login.php');</script>"; //redirects to login.php
    }//else
    {
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $userid;
    }
}//if

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is my homepage.php

```
<div class="Main"> 
<?php
// You'd put this code at the top of any "protected" page you create

// Always start this first
session_start();

if ( isset( $_SESSION['UserID'] ) ) {
    // Grab user data from the database using the user_id
    // Let them access the "logged in only" pages
} else {
    // Redirect them to the login page
    header("Location:Login.php");
}
?>

This is the home page
   <img src="images/homepic.jpg" width="1000" height="628" alt=""/> 



</div>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not working"?

Comment: You are redirecting to the homepage.php before you set `$_SESSION['UserID']`

Comment: A little sensible code indentation would your code much easier to read.

Comment: When trying to change the indentation in your post I found what are several potential syntax errors.

Comment: When I log in Object not found page comes up

Comment: So Should  the session be set here then? 


if ($username == $table_users && ($password == $table_password)) 

{
    $_SESSION['UserID'] = $userid;
    
if ($table_role == 1)
header ("location: CHomePage.php"); // takes the user to the Customer Homepage 
else if ($table_role == 2) 
header ("location: HomePage.php"); // takes the user to the Staff Homeage
}//if
else 
{
echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Username or Password!');</script>"; //Prompts the user 
echo "<script>window.location.assign('login.php');</script>"; //redirects to login.php
}//else

Comment: It's hard to decipher the code in the comments but you should set the session as soon as the login is successful. Then you can redirect.

Answer (score 1):

As your comment says:

```
// Always start this first
```

And yet, you have ignored your own advice and put this above it:

```
<div class="Main">
```

The call to `session_start()` has to be the first thing on the page. Before any includes, before any other code, before any HTML output.

---

I also noticed this in your code:

```php
    {
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $userid;
    }
```

With no accompanying `if` statement. Is that intentional? You would be well served by following standard coding style, as a lot of novice mistakes I see here are masked by poor indentation and/or inconsistent whitespace usage. See [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) which are boring standards documents, but they are not technical, and are quite easy to read.

Answer (score -1):

Be sure first of all that you do understand how sessions work:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

When you start a session, PHP will coin a random "cookie" value and send that cookie in the HTML headers of the next page sent.  The user's browser will store that cookie and provide it on subsequent HTTP exchanges.  But, *you must be sure that the `set-cookie:` header actually arrives!*  A "redirect" won't do it:  you have to send a page.

Comment: There's no reason you can't send a cookie with a 301 redirect.